# Android referring to MainActivity's instance variable from a fragment

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fragments

I have a navigation drawer set up in my MainActivity and I want to access it from a fragment.

```
NavigationDrawerFragment.java
public void updateDrawer() {
..setAdapter(...);
}


MainActivity.java
public NavigationDrawerFragment mNavigationDrawerFragment;


Fragment_Login.java
(inside some function)...
MainActivity.this.mNavigationDrawerFragment.updateDrawer();
...
```

You can see that I want to update my Navigation Drawer view after I've logged in from my Login Fragment. However, I am unable to make the call unless I am able to reference the MainActivity instance. Calling MainActivity.this throws a compile error:

`...MainActivity is not an enclosing class`

Anyway to bypass this? I've also tried getActivity().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
((MainActivity)getActivity).mNavigationDrawerFragment.updateDrawer();
```

But not the best way, you should take a look at [Interfaces](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/createinterface.html)

Comment: This worked very well thanks. How does Interfaces help?